# What is causing a negative bias in my super-sampling simulation?

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics

I'm developing a little test program to see if it is feasible to add noise to an ADC to gain oversampled bits. A little theory, before we begin. Nyquist's sampling theorem suggests that an increase in one bit of resolution requires four additional samples, and in general, n more bits requires 2^(n+1) more samples. I'm simulating a perfect 10 bit ADC which returns a value from 0..1023 monotonically and with no noise for an input from 0-2V.

To gain more bits, it is necessary to add randomly distributed noise (it doesn't have to be actually random, but it does have to *appear* random, like white noise.) The problem I'm having is although the resolution is increasing, the actual reading is offset by some small negative amount. Here's one sample output for an input of 1 volt (reference is 2 volts, so the count should be exactly half for an monotonic ADC):

```
10 bits:  512         volts:  1.0
11 bits:  1024        volts:  1.0
12 bits:  2046        volts:  0.9990234375
13 bits:  4093        volts:  0.999267578125
14 bits:  8189        volts:  0.999633789062
15 bits:  16375       volts:  0.999450683594
16 bits:  32753       volts:  0.999542236328
17 bits:  65509       volts:  0.999588012695
18 bits:  131013      volts:  0.999549865723
24 bits:  8384565     volts:  0.999518036842
28 bits:  134152551   volts:  0.999514393508
```

In fact, no matter how many times I run the simulation I'm always ending up with around ~0.9995, instead of 1; and the last value should be 134,217,728, not 134,152,551, which is about 65,771 out - or around 1/4 of the extra 18 bits of resolution (coincidence? I am diving by 4.) I suspect my PRNG is biased in some way, but I am using the default Mersenne Twister that comes with Python.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# 
#  Demonstrates how oversampling/supersampling with noise can be used
#  to improve the resolution of an ADC reading.
#
#  Public domain.
#

import random, sys

volts = 1.000
reference = 2.000
noise = 0.01
adc_res = 10

def get_rand_bit():
    return random.choice([-1, 1])

def volts_with_noise():
    if get_rand_bit() == 1:
        return volts + (noise * random.random() * get_rand_bit())
    else:
        return volts

def sample_adc(v):
    # Sample ADC with adc_res bits on given voltage.
    frac = v / reference
    frac = max(min(frac, 1.0), 0.0) # clip voltage
    return int(frac * (2 ** adc_res))

def adc_do_no_noise_sample():
    return sample_adc(volts)

def adc_do_noise_sample(extra_bits_wanted):
    # The number of extra samples required to gain n bits (according to 
    # Nyquist) is 2^(n+1). So for 1 extra bit, we need to sample 4 times.
    samples = 2 ** (extra_bits_wanted + 1)
    print "Sampling ", samples, " times for ", extra_bits_wanted, " extra bits."
    # Sample the number of times and add the totals.
    total = 0
    for i in range(samples):
        if i % 100000 == 99999:
            print float(i * 100) / samples
            sys.stdout.flush()
        total += sample_adc(volts_with_noise())
    # Divide by two (to cancel out the +1 in 2^(n+1)) and return the integer part.
    return int(total / 2)

def convert_integer_to_volts(val, num_bits):
    # Get a fraction.
    frac = float(val) / (2 ** num_bits)
    # Multiply by the reference.
    return frac * reference

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # First test: we want a 10 bit sample.
    _10_bits = adc_do_no_noise_sample()
    # Next, create additional samples.
    _11_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(1)
    _12_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(2)
    _13_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(3)
    _14_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(4)
    _15_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(5)
    _16_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(6)
    _17_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(7)
    _18_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(8)
    _24_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(14)
    _28_bits = adc_do_noise_sample(18)
    # Print results both as integers and voltages.
    print "10 bits: ", _10_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_10_bits, 10)
    print "11 bits: ", _11_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_11_bits, 11)
    print "12 bits: ", _12_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_12_bits, 12)
    print "13 bits: ", _13_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_13_bits, 13)
    print "14 bits: ", _14_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_14_bits, 14)
    print "15 bits: ", _15_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_15_bits, 15)
    print "16 bits: ", _16_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_16_bits, 16)
    print "17 bits: ", _17_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_17_bits, 17)
    print "18 bits: ", _18_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_18_bits, 18)
    print "24 bits: ", _24_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_24_bits, 24)
    print "28 bits: ", _28_bits, "  volts: ", convert_integer_to_volts(_28_bits, 28)
```

I'd appreciate any suggestions on this. My plan is eventually to take this to a low cost microcontroller to implement a high resolution ADC. Speed will be fairly important, so I will probably be using an LFSR to generate PRNG bits, which won't be half as good as a Mersenne twister but should be good enough for most uses, and hopefully good enough for this.

Comment: Could you add a hint about the meaning of "ADC"?

Comment: I am also a bit unsure about your intent.  "Resolution" means "smallest discernible details" to me.  If you have details below the resolution, you are missing that information.  How should adding noise be able to add that information back?  Are you using some different meaning of "resolution"?

Comment: @Svante - Analog to digital converter.

Comment: @Svante, the voltage source could be considered infinite in resolution. Adding noise causes the counts on the ADC to jump around a bit which increases the resolution. It's hard to explain without a background in informational theory (which I don't really have, but it's gathered knowledge mostly from books and websites.)

Comment: not that it seems to remove/add bias but your implementation of `volts_with_noise()` looks a bit funny to me: 50% of the samplings will have zero noise added. Is that on purpose ?

Comment: interesting question by the way, could have been asked as well on http://stats.stackexchange.com/ or http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `sample_adc(..)` you probably want to round instead of truncating (systematically round towards  negative infinity), i.e. do:

```
return int(frac * (2 ** adc_res) + 0.5)
```

instead of

```
return int(frac * (2 ** adc_res))
```

Then the deviations from one are not always on the same side:

```
10 bits:  512   volts:  1.0
11 bits:  1025   volts:  1.0009765625
12 bits:  2046   volts:  0.9990234375
13 bits:  4100   volts:  1.0009765625
14 bits:  8196   volts:  1.00048828125
15 bits:  16391   volts:  1.00042724609
16 bits:  32784   volts:  1.00048828125
17 bits:  65528   volts:  0.999877929688
18 bits:  131111   volts:  1.00029754639
24 bits:  8388594   volts:  0.99999833107
28 bits:  134216558   volts:  0.999991282821
```

Although to check the bias one would e.g. call `adc_do_noise_sample(..)` e.g. 10'000 times (for each resolution) and calculate the mean bias and the uncertainty on this mean (and check whether how compatible it is with zero).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your noise source is biased.  I'm not familiar with the Mersenne Twister, but I do know for a fact that LFSR pseudo-random noise generators **always** have a slight bias.  You can make the bias arbitrarily small by extending the LFSR's length, but it will always be there.

Comment: I did a quick test taking the mean of 100,000 numbers from my random generator, and it was around -0.0001 to +0.0001, so not very much bias at all (about what would be predicted.) The problem seems to be a very consistent bias towards ~0.9995.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the domain here, but if you're using python2, you may be suffering from unintended integer division. There's some approaches to deal with this.

```
>>> 10 / 3
3
>>> 10 * 1.0 / 3
3.3333333333333335
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 10 / 3
3.3333333333333335
>>> 10 // 3
3
```